# How to show that any LP in equational form can be reduced to an optimization problem on the regular simplex?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

An LP is given in the form :

$max\langle c,x\rangle$ subject to $Ax=b,x\geq 0$.

I'm trying to show that any such problem can be reduced to a problem of the form

$max\langle c,x\rangle$ subject to $Ax=b,x\geq 0,\displaystyle \sum {x_j}=1$.

I think I'll somehow have to modify the problem by dividing by some quantity. However, I can't quite show this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assume that $Ax=b$, $x\ge 0$ is a bounded set.** Then $\exists M>0\colon \sum x_k\le M$. Introduce 
$$
t=1-\sum\frac{x_k}{M}\ge 0,\qquad\text{and}\qquad z=\left[\matrix{\frac{x}{M}\\ t}\right].
$$
Then the problem becomes
$$
\max\left[\matrix{Mc\\ 0}\right]^Tz\qquad\text{subject to}\qquad [A\ 0]z=\frac{b}{M},\ z\ge 0,\ \sum z_j=1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. For example, $\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}}\mathbf{1}^{T}x$
subject to $x\geq0$ is of this form. The problem is unbounded. However,
any problem with the convex combination constraint $\sum x_{j}=1$
is bounded.